# Vertical alignment text and DropDownList

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

This is my text and DropDownList:

```
  <h3>this is test: @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files), "Select...", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })</h3>
```

[image]

And i want it become alignment

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>this is test: @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files), "Select...", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;"})</h3>
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/cuK36/

Comment: If you use Firebug or similar, and see the generated HTML... the style is there? You can try setting the same style to the H3. It seems that your DropDownList is bigger than the H3 text and that could be the problem (but I doubt it).